# Как избавиться от страха использования хэш функции?

Tags: php, хеширование, md5

Я читал что для получения коллизии md5 нужно сгенерировать 2^64 значения. Но что если от этого будет зависеть моя жизнь? Что если от этого упадёт самолёт?

Comment: выберите другую хэш функцию.

Comment: Добавьте немного соли, для вкуса

Comment: *для получения коллизии md5 нужно сгенерировать 2^64 значения.* Для **гарантированного** получения коллизии надо сгенерировать 1+2^64 **уникальных** значения. Для получения же коллизии с вероятностью, скажем, в 50%, надо гора-а-аздо меньше значений...

Comment: @BigTows Соль это для криптографии.

Comment: *Что если от этого упадёт самолёт?* Просто не стой там, где падают самолёты...

Comment: «от этого» — от чего конкретно?

Comment: Какую задачу решаете? Ответьте себе: правильно ли я понимаю назначение хеша? Мне кажется, что нет. Если нужен глобально уникальный идентификатор - используйте другое решение. Если сравниваете файлы, сравнивайте побайтово, а не их хеши. Хотите еще больше избавиться от коллизий - используйте SHA2-512, а еще лучше - сразу несколько хеш функций. Боитесь, что в сам хеш может прийти с ошибкам - добавьте избыточности.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема несколько шире, чем вы ее поставили.

Просто в критическом коде, от которого зависит ваша жизнь, не нужно использовать подходы/функции которые по своей природе могут породить ошибку.

Критический код должен быть скучным, прямолинейным, лишенным изысков, но железобетонно надежным.

В зависимости от задачи:

- храните данные в изначальном виде, не хешируя
- используйте автоинкрементные идентификаторы
- используйте хеш только для быстрой выборки, а конечный результат дополнительно сверяйте по исходным данным
- и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Еще в 2011 году выпустили и утвердили [RFC 6151](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6151), в котором признали, что MD5 нельзя использовать там, где нужна защита от коллизий:

> MD5 is no longer acceptable where collision resistance is required
> such as digital signatures.

С того времени прошло уже 7 лет. Существует множество других хеш-функций, которые используют вместо MD5.

Comment: Какие например?

Comment: Все семейство SHA2: SHA224/SHA256/SHA384/SHA512

Comment: По-моему вы немного не про то отвечаете...

Answer (score 0):

Смотря где используется:

- Можно сгенерировать другой функцией, с более редкими коллизиями.
- Можно делать двойной md5 (через конкатенацию), первый от значения другой от времени.
- Можно добавлять к хешу последовательность.

Если требуется 100% уникальность в пределах своей системы/базы данных, то используй 3 вариант, но нужно иметь ввиду что можно будет анализируя хеши понять сколько их сгенерировано и тд.

Если требуется уникальность глобальная, то принято использовать GUID.

Comment: Будет забавно если именно ваше добавление и приведёт к коллизии :)

Comment: Это не возможно в пределах своей системы/базы. Вот с другими системами возможно.

Comment: @МихаилГригорьев На самом деле все проще, хеши используются повсеместно, в том числе и самые простейшие с огромным количеством коллизий. Но везде, где коллизия значима (в том же поиске по хеш-таблицам, например), программист сделает проверку изначальных значений

Comment: В общем это параноя. Кто будет заниматься настолько важными задачами, то он таким вопросом не озадачиться.

Comment: > Можно делать двойной md5, первый от значения другой от времени.

если хеши совпали после первого хеширования, то они совпадут и после второго и последующих.

Comment: @KoVadim речь вроде про конкатенацию хэша данных и хэша времени генерации, а не двоейное вычисленеи

Comment: Конечно же конкатенация, смысла от завернутого нет.